# Partially applied Function2 with first and second argument

Tags: scala, currying

Given a method

```
def f(a: String, b: String) = ???
```

I want to get both partially applied function (with first argument and with the second one).

I've written the following code :

```
def fst = f _ curried "a"
def snd = (s: String) => (f _ curried)(s)("b")
```

Is there a better way ?

[update] snd could be written shorter `def snd = (f _ curried)((_: String))("b")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
def fst = f("a", (_: String))
def snd = f((_: String), "b")
```

But note it recalculates the partially applied functions on every call, so I'd prefer `val` (or maybe `lazy val`) instead of `def` in most circumstances.

Comment: `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => f("a", x$1))`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use multiple parameter lists:

```
def f(a: String)(b: String) = ???
```

No args supplied:

```
def fst = f _
```

First arg supplied:

```
def fst = f("a")
```

Only second arg supplied:

```
def fst = f(_: String)("b")
```

All args supplied:

```
def snd = f("a")("b")
```

If you are currying args in the same order they are defined then this syntax is a bit cleaner than the one used in the question.